# ¿Cómo puedo hacer click en el botón de Adjuntar archivo en Gmail con Python + Selenium?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

Trato de hacer click en el botón que aparece en gmail con selenium, pero no he podido hacer click en el.

Este es el código que tengo:

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('div.aaA').send_keys(r"C:\Users\micomputer\Desktop\perritos\dog.png")
```

Al ejecutarlo, obtengo un error que no puede ser encontrado el botón. ¿Alguien puede echarme una mano? De antemano agradezco su apoyo. Saludos!

Comment: Fíjate si esta respuesta te ayuda https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/468423/169744

Comment: No, no me ayuda, de hecho, encuentro confuso el uso de gmail, porque su código suele ser dinámico, no sé si le puedas dar una checada y ver si puedes conseguirlo

Comment: El punto de la otra respuesta era que a veces el botón no se ha cargado cuando tu le dices que lo cliquee entonces tienes que esperar hasta que aparezca. A lo mejor no lo estaba haciendo.

Comment: De hecho sí carga, porque le añadí un time.sleep(10)

Comment: Ya tengo la solución

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Por si a alguien en algún momento le llegase a servir. Ya encontré la solución:

Para cargar un archivo con Selenium enviando la ruta del archivo de carga, se debe usar este localizador de elementos `//input[@type="file"]`
Entonces en lugar de

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('div.aaA').send_keys(r"C:\Users\micomputer\Desktop\perritos\dog.png")
```

Usamos:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//input[@type="file"]').send_keys(r"C:\Users\micomputer\Desktop\perritos\dog.png")
```